# How could I select only needed values in repository pattern?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, repository-pattern

I read many articles about well designed queries to deal with performance, specially when is necessary a large amount of data. One of "tips" was selecting only needed columns, with `Select` operator, for example. But the only way I could think of doing that and returning domain entities was using `IQueryable<T>`, but this isn't a good practice too. So how could I return to my Application layer only the properties I will use to construct my Viewmodels? Specially when this viewmodels are in the application layer and not in the infrastructure one.

Answer (score 0):

The way of `IQueryable<T>` will expose entities or models in infrastructure to application layer. If you are concerning about this, then you may do something like below:

1. Create a mapper between view model and entity, it tells repository which columns are needed by application layer.
2. Inside of repository, it will leverage tech like ADO.Net or EF to maintain underlying connection to datasource/database. So just construct the T-SQL with the needed columns here for the specific query.

Hope it can help you.